# Corona: Restart scene when game completed

Tags: lua, coronasdk

When a player has completed a game, i would like for the scene to be restarted, i.e i want to reload the current scene. I have tried storyboard:reloadScene() without success. 
I also tried to purge the scene and then reload it, also without any result.

```
local function onEveryFramePoop()
if(foodBalls) then
    for i = foodBalls.numChildren, 1, -1 do
        local ball = foodBalls[i]

        if(ball.y > 200 and not(ball.isBeingPooped)) then
            ball.isBeingPooped = true

            local function tempRemove()
                if(foodBalls.numChildren)then
                    ball:removeSelf()
                    ball = nil
                    print("removed")
                end
            end
            physics.removeBody(ball)

            transition.to(ball, {time = 2000, y = 400, onComplete = tempRemove})
            audio.play(fartSound)
        end
    end

    if(foodBalls.numChildren == 0 and food.numChildren == 2) then

        reward.playRewardAnimation()
        Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", onEveryFramePoop)     
        timer.performWithDelay(2500, reloadSceneWithDelay)  
    end
  end
end

function reloadSceneWithDelay()
     storyboard.gotoScene("levels.levelDigestion") -- **HERE I WANT TO RESTART SCENE**
end
```

Nothing seems to happen at all. What am i missing here ?

Comment: Did you mean `if(foodBalls.numChildren > 0)then` instead of `if(foodBalls.numChildren)then`?

Comment: That is not the problem! i simply need to reload the scene when reloadSceneWithDelay is called.

Comment: Yes, it is not the main problem.  But it is very frequent C programmers' mistake to write in Lua `if(a)then` instead of `if a~=0 then`.

Comment: Thanks, Like i said. The code is working fine, it's the reloading of the scene that does not work

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use storyboard but, you can try this :

Create a black scene in storyboard
Then, when you want to restart, just go to black scene and afterwards to the scene where you want to go.

The problem may be about that you are trying to call a module from itself.